# Highest number of bytes taken from Rfc2898DeriveBytes class

Tags: security, cryptography, pbkdf2

I know very little about PBKDF2 and its processing steps. To know more I started reading about it and looking at codes as well. I have seen codes like this in Google. For AES-128bit the value of N is 16. My question, for random use how far can I increase the value of N? can it be 50? or 100? is there any upper limit?

```
        string password = "123456789";
        string salt = "987654321";
        Rfc2898DeriveBytes keyGenerator = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, Encoding .UTF8 .GetBytes (salt ),10000);
        byte[] key1 = keyGenerator.GetBytes(N);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [RFC 2898](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2898.txt) maximum length of derived key is `(2^32 - 1) * hLen` where hLen is 
the length in octets of pseudorandom function output.

[Rfc2898DeriveBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes(v=vs.110).aspx) class in .NET framework you are referring to in your code sample uses HMAC-SHA1 pseudorandom function which outputs 20 bytes so the maximum theoretical value of N in your case is 85899345900.

Comment: strange! I used this code to get 32bytes key for AES-256bit and it works great both for encryption and decryption! but your saying 20bytes.......Then how did that happend!!!

Comment: I am hoping may be the rest of the bytes were  zeros .

Comment: Since `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` class outputs 20bytes its good for AES-128bit. Is there any standard KDF that outputs 32byte for AES-256bit?

Comment: @Giliweed 20 bytes long is just the output of HMAC-SHA1 pseudorandom function which is used by the internal implementation of PBKDF2. When you request PBKDF2 to derive more than 20 bytes, it calls HMAC-SHA1 again and again until the requested number of bytes is available. See RFC 2898 for more details about the algorithm or try to implement it yourself. You can safely use `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` class to derive 256bit keys.

Comment: OOO yess!!! how silly I am!  its the value of N your talking 85899345900 !!! and I need only 32 .... So its sure to work! :) sorry that I misunderstood and asked those silly questions. Thanks for bringing me back to earth. :)